# Reading Xml into DataSet

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no" ?> 
<!-- This file represents The Details of the user and the responces: --> 
<Survey>
  <Clientdetails>
    <ClientName xmlns="yash" /> 
    <ClientCompanyName xmlns="lnt" /> 
    <ClientTelNo. xmlns="546" /> 
    <ClientMobileNo xmlns="56" /> 
    <ClientEMail xmlns="56" /> 
  </Clientdetails>
  <ClientResponces>
    <Question1>
      <responce>1</responce> 
    </Question1>
    <Question2>
      <responce>2</responce> 
    </Question2>
    <Question3>
      <responce>3</responce> 
    </Question3>
    <Question4>
      <responce>3</responce> 
    </Question4>
    <Question5>
      <Question5.1>
        <responce>3</responce> 
      </Question5.1>
      <Question5.2>
        <responce>3</responce> 
      </Question5.2>
      <Question5.3>
        <responce>2</responce> 
      </Question5.3>
      <Question5.4>
        <responce>3</responce> 
      </Question5.4>
      <Question5.5>
        <responce>3</responce> 
      </Question5.5>
      <Question5.6>
        <responce>3</responce> 
      </Question5.6>
      <Question5.7>
        <responce>3</responce> 
      </Question5.7>
      <Question5.8>
        <responce>2</responce> 
      </Question5.8>
      <Question5.9>
        <responce>1</responce> 
      </Question5.9>
      <Question5.10>
        <responce>2</responce> 
      </Question5.10>
      <Question5.11>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.11>
      <Question5.12>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.12>
      <Question5.13>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.13>
      <Question5.14>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.14>
      <Question5.15>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.15>
      <Question5.16>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.16>
      <Question5.17>
        <responce>0</responce> 
      </Question5.17>
    </Question5>
  </ClientResponces>
</Survey>
```

I want to read this data into a DataSet. I want just the responses given by the client, and for 5th question I want the average of its 17 sub-questions.

For example, the DataSet should only contain this:

```
1
2
3
3
4
```

How to do this in C#?

Comment: eh?? What is your question? You can just open the xml file and insert the data.

Comment: Edited the question to display XML properly.

Comment: Show us what you have tried and ask a specific problem. I'm tagging this as homework, until I see some effort.

Comment: @Cerebrus: I'm not sure that preliminary tagging is helpful. When you see some effort, you're going to remove the tags, at which point this becomes a wiki, and no-one can earn rep anymore. That's two useless and avoidable edits because you had a suspicion. Not so nice.

Comment: @Tomalak: Can you clarify why this would become a Wiki if tags are removed? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Because any edit counts towards a limit, at which point the post becomes a wiki regardless. Last time I checked this limit was at seven edits.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Didn't know that and I'll keep that threshold in mind, in future. :-)

Answer (score 3):

That xml is pretty... horrible. My first suggestion would be to run it through an xslt transformation to get it into something more normal, that can be loaded with `Load`. Currently, it is abusing namespaces **horribly**.

Alternatively, forget `DataSet`, and parse it with `XmlDocument` or similar.

Here's an approach using `XmlDocument` (and using LINQ just for the average, to save a few lines of code):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);
foreach (XmlElement el in doc.SelectNodes("//responce")) {
    Console.WriteLine(el.ParentNode.Name + "=" + el.InnerText);
}
XmlNodeList fiveAnswers = doc.SelectNodes(
      "/Survey/ClientResponces/Question5/*/responce");
double avg = fiveAnswers.Cast<XmlElement>()
     .Average(el => int.Parse(el.InnerText));
Console.WriteLine(avg);
```

For example of *normal* xml:

```
<question num="1">
  <response>1</response>
</question>
...
<question num="5">
  <response num="1">1</response>
  <response num="2">3</response>
  ...
</question>
```

or something comparable. Don't use the element name to infer identity.

Comment: -1. He can't load XML into a Dataset and you suggest XSLT? Yes, correct but does it help.

Comment: Not sure if you should include an "id" attribute that can contain duplicate values.

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Much, thank you. :-) (I know that as long as nothing else is defined (DTD/schema), an attribute named "id" has no special meaning in XML.)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 XmlDataDocument doc = new XmlDataDocument();
doc.LoadXml(<your string>);
DataSet ds = doc.DataSet;
```

You can then use LINQ to select distinct from the document.

**update**

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in doc.SelectNodes("\\Survey\ClientResponses"))
  {
     string text = node.InnerText;
  }
```

(not tested! your nested cases will be tricky!)

Comment: Re your comment - he can't load **that** xml into a dataset because it is so horribly, horribly borked.

Comment: True... it's a bit of a mess.